# My python code looks up only last value from the loop

Tags: python

I have a file called IP2.txt and this file contains 2 rows as shown below.

```
103.201.150.209
113.170.129.113
```

My code goes like this it reads the file IP2 and looks up the website search

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re

fh = open('IP2.txt')

for line in fh:

        ip = line.rstrip()

        print(ip)

        loads = {'q':line.rstrip(),'engine':1}

        r = requests.get('https://fortiguard.com/search',params=loads)

#       print(r.url)

#       print(r.text)

Link_text = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(Link_text, 'lxml')

for product in soup.find_all('section', class_='iprep'):

    product_title = product.find("a").text

print(ip+':'+ product_title)

fh.close()
```

The output of the above code is like this.

```
103.201.150.209

113.170.129.113

113.170.129.113:Malicious Websites
```

As you can see it's reading the last line and skipping the first value: `103.201.150.209`

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your indentation is not correct, causing lines that should be part of your loops to be executed only once after those loops are over. You are probably looking for this:

```
with open('IP2.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        ip = line.rstrip()
        print(ip)
        loads = {'q':line.rstrip(), 'engine':1}
        r = requests.get('https://fortiguard.com/search', params=loads)
        # do the following for ALL ips
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        for product in soup.find_all('section', class_='iprep'):
            product_title = product.find("a").text
            # print ALL products
            print(ip + ':' + product_title)
```

Also note the use of `with` which will auto-close your file even if something goes wrong in between.

Comment: Thanks for the  inputs and advice on using the with option while opening the file

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding `r` value every time in your for loop. You can create a `list` outside of your loop and append to it every time in loop. Other way would be to do all your BeautifulSoup operations and printing inside your for loop, then you will be getting your printout for every `r`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to loop over the return values from `requests`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

with open('IP2.txt') as fh:
    texts = []
    for line in fh:
            ip = line.rstrip()
            print(ip)
            loads = {'q':line.rstrip(),'engine':1}
            r = requests.get('https://fortiguard.com/search',params=loads)
            texts.append(r.text)
    for text in texts:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')

        for product in soup.find_all('section', class_='iprep'):
            product_title = product.find("a").text
            print(ip+':'+ product_title)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your time and inputs.
quamrana
Also, I liked your idea of assigning the value to texts = []

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is :

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re
fh = open('IP2.txt')
for line in fh:
        ip = line.rstrip()
        print(ip)
        loads = {'q':line.rstrip(),'engine':1}
        r = requests.get('https://fortiguard.com/search',params=loads)
        Link_text = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(Link_text, 'lxml')
        for product in soup.find_all('section', class_='iprep'):
            product_title = product.find("a").text
            print(ip+':'+ product_title)
fh.close()
```

Seems more like an indentation problem.

Comment: Thanks, i figured out this was the issue and got i working, but this post is helping me

Comment: @DeepakKumar glad to know. Good luck.